# How do I display Django data from a related model of a related model?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display data from several models that are related together through a QuerySet. My ultimate goal is to display some information from the Site model, and some information from the Ppack model, based on a date range filter of the sw_delivery_date in the Site model.

Here are my models:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    mnemonic = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    assigned_tech = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    hw_handoff_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    sw_delivery_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    go_live_date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    web_url = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
    idp_url = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '(' + self.mnemonic + ') ' + self.site_name

class Ring(models.Model):
    ring = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "6." + str(self.ring)

class Ppack(models.Model):
    ppack = models.IntegerField()
    ring = models.ForeignKey('Ring', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ring) + " pp" + str(self.ppack)

class Code_Release(models.Model):
    Inhouse = 'I'
    Test = 'T'
    Live = 'L'
    Ring_Location_Choices = (
            (Inhouse, 'Inhouse'),
            (Test, 'Test'),
            (Live, 'Live'),
                             )

    site_id = models.ForeignKey('Site', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = Ring_Location_Choices, blank = True, null = True)
    release = models.ForeignKey('Ppack', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "site:" + str(self.site_id) + ", " + self.type + " = " + str(self.release)
```

If I use the following,

```
today = datetime.date.today()
future = datetime.timedelta(days=60)
new_deliveries = Site.objects.select_related().filter(sw_delivery_date__range=[today, (today + future)])
```

I can get all of the objects in the Site model that meet my criteria, however, because there is no relation from Site to Code_Release (there's a one-to-many coming the other way), I can't get at the Code_Release data.

If I run a for loop, I can iterate through every Site returned from the above query, and select the data from the Code_Release model, which allows me to get the related data from the Ppack and Ring models.

```
site_itl = {}
itl = {}
for delivery in new_deliveries:
    releases = Code_Release.objects.select_related().filter(site_id = delivery.id)

    for rel in releases:
        itl[rel.id] = rel.release

    site_itl[delivery.id] = itl
```

But, that seems overly complex to me, with multiple database hits and possibly a difficult time parsing through that in the template.

Based on that, I was thinking that I needed to select from the Code_Release model. That relates back to both the Site model and the Ppack model (which relates to the Ring model). I've struggled to make the right query / access the data in this way that accomplishes what I want, but I feel this is the right way to go.

How would I best accomplish this?

Comment: Please clarify - the goal is to retrieve a set of Code_Release objects? What relations do you need in addition to those?

Comment: I want to be able to display the following:
Site name, sw_delivery_date, release info (the str representation of the Ppack model), and the assigned_tech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RelatedManager here. When you declare ForeignKey, Django allows you to access reverse relationship. To be specific, let's say that you have multiple code releases that are pointing to one specific site. You can access them all via site object by using `<your_model_name_lowercase>_set` attribute. So in your case:

```
site.code_release_set.all()
```

will return QuerySet of all code release objects that have ForeignKey to object `site`

Comment: Thanks so much - this is exactly what I needed. I can use `site.code_release_set.get(type="I").release` to get the specific piece of data (the release name for the site's inhouse environment).

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. While I'm in the shell, this works perfectly. But I can't use `site.code_release_set.get(type="I").release` while in the template. I get the following error - `Could not parse the remainder: (type="I").release from 'site.code_release_set.get(type="I").release'`

Comment: @RobPeterson because you're not supposed to perform filtering within Django templates. Perhaps there are many other solutions, but the first that came to my mind was to declare custom property(or method) in Site model, where you access things that you need (e.g. create method `get_release` that have following statement `return self.code_release_set.get(type="I").release`). Then you just access it in your template `site.get_release`

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. Working just as I wanted now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Releases from a Site object. First, you can put a related_name to have a friendly name of the reverse relation between the models:

```
site_id = models.ForeignKey('Site', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="releases")
```

and then, from a Site object you can make normal queries to Release model:

```
site.releases.all()
site.releases.filter(...)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. @mateuszb had the info I needed. This added both some additional understanding and the knowledge of what I can do with the "related_name" piece.